# Showing advertisements in the middle of playing video ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, ads

I want to show advertisement while playing video in app like youtube. My app contains videos, while seeing video, in the middle of the video i need to show the advertisement like youtube. I checked with Admob, but i didn't get solution. Anyone having idea of how to do this?

Comment: there are 3 option available to play the Ads in your current video, pre, mid & post roll  so in here you need to maintain the cue point in your video,once its reached automatically its shows, for e.g brightcove SDk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interactive Media Ads SDKs allows iOS native application developers to request and track VAST ads (ProRol,MidRol,PostRol,Skipable etc) in the iOS (9.0+) environment. 
It supports AVPlayer as well.
[Here is is complete documentation of IMA SDK](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/ios/)

Comment: Thank you. I got idea about Interactive Media Ads.